# What does Double Up mean?

Tags: poker-night-2

In *Poker Night 2*, I received the bounty goal "Double Up". I'm not really much of a poker player, and there's no ingame explanation for this term, so I'm not really sure what it's asking. What does it mean to "double up" for the goal? What exactly do I have to do?

[image: Poker Night 2 bounties]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doubling up is winning a hand, doubling the amount of chips in your possession in the process.

Basically you must go all in and win. Technically to double up precisely you have to do that against one opponent with more chips than you do, but I *think* winning more than that by going in a showdown with three or more people also counts.

Comment: As to the top answer, it can't be any showdown, only those who are with guys with more chips than you. I've tried many times and it hasn't seemed to work.

Comment: You have to double your chips.  Thus a single opponent would have to have exactly your chips, and you both go all in, or you win an all in pot against multiple opponents.  This is how I did it.  Went all in with 15k or so, three other people also went all in.

Comment: @kexlox your opponent having as many chips as you do is unnecessary. If you go all in vs a player with less chips than you do, you'll only bet for as many chips as he does. In the first game this was made explicit by putting the excess chips in a side pot only you are eligible to win. In Poker Night 2 you are instantly awarded the excess chips to your funds.

Comment: But surely that wouldn't count as doubling up then.  If I have 15k, you have 10k, and I go all in and you call, I end with 25k, not the 30k needed to have doubled up.

Comment: @Kexlox A has 15, B has 10. B goes all in, A calls (or viceversa, or A bets 12 and B calls, or whatever). A and B showdown for a pot of 20. B wins. A now has 5, B has 20. B doubled up.

Comment: @badp correct, but if A had won, he would not have doubled up.  This is the scenario I interpreted your comment to mean.

Comment: @Kexlox I swapped the roles to make the sentence easier to... write. In my comment "you" is who doubles up.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to go all in. You can double up by having every player to bet at least 1/4 of what you have.